# Automatically Switch Mouse-Button Profile Like Logitech Software?

Tags: mouse, logitech

So my Logitech G502 USB cord mouse has 11 buttons.
In Windows, I can set different button profiles.
Each profile assigns certain actions to the buttons.
And it switches profiles automatically based on which application I'm using.

*For example, one mouse button goes back when I'm using Firefox,
but the same button plays music when using Piano Roll Composer.*

P.S. Piper doesn't work right now. When it did work on a previous Bodhi LInux installation, it wouldn't properly apply/save button profiles.

What I've Tried So Far:

- Searched here on Ask Ubuntu.
- Asking on Bodhi Linux Discord.
- Searching on Reddit.
- Installing 2 different Logitech software on Bodhi Linux using PlayOnLinux
- Searched on Snap store and Flathub

P.S. I noticed that some of my mouse button settings saved onto my mouse. Not all of it, though, and also, not the other profiles for other apps.

Edit:
Bodhi Linux 5.1.0 AppPack.
Ubuntu 18.04.
Logitech doesn't have any drivers on their website.
They have software for Windows (a new one that doesn't work properly, and an older version that does).

Comment: First what version of Ubuntu? Second does this mouse have any drive for Ubuntu or does the mfg say it works with Linux? Lastly In windows is there an app you needed to install for all the features of the mouse to work?

Comment: Bodhi Linux 5.1.0 AppPack.
Ubuntu 18.04.
Logitech doesn't have any drivers on their website.
They have software for Windows (a new one that doesn't work properly, and an older version that does). Like I said, i tried installing both with PlayOnLinux, but it didn't work.

Comment: I do not think a driver app will work with playonlinux so you will most likely have to live with the way it is. It is up to the mfg to make the drivers.